# selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException Error

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I aimed to scrape address data from the website that indicated in the code below and i encountered with this error.

```
File "c:\Users\efede\OneDrive\Masaüstü\Scrapping\pythonfiles\gCharge.py", line 15, in <module>
    WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'#map_canvas > div > div > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(2) > div > div:nth-child(4) > div > div > div > div.gm-style-iw.gm-style-iw-c > div > div > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(2) > h5')))
  File "C:\Users\efede\OneDrive\Masaüstü\Scrapping\scrappingenv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 95, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

CODE:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


path = r"C:\Users\efede\OneDrive\Masaüstü\exeler\chromedriver.exe"
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
  
driver.get("https://www.g-charge.com.tr/Map.Aspx")
WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'#map_canvas > div > div > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(2) > div > div:nth-child(4) > div > div > div > div.gm-style-iw.gm-style-iw-c > div > div > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(2) > h5')))
kaynak=driver.page_source
soup=BeautifulSoup(kaynak,"html.parser")
basliklar= driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'#map_canvas > div > div > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(2) > div > div:nth-child(4) > div > div > div > div.gm-style-iw.gm-style-iw-c > div > div > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(2) > h5')
titles= [baslik.text for baslik in basliklar]
print(titles)
```

I tried to look at the other questions in this website but haven't foun anything useful yet. How can i fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems awfully close to an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). While not explicitly stated, you are after the charger details from that map. Selenium is not the appropriate tool of choice here. You can obtain that information by inspecting the Network calls made by JS on that page, and scraping the API endpoint where the info is sourced from:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

headers= {
    'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/113.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
}

r = requests.get("https://www.g-charge.com.tr/Services/Charger.aspx?Operation=GetChargers", headers=headers)
df = pd.json_normalize(r.json())
print(df)
```

Result in terminal:

```
    Id  ChargerNumber   ChargerTitle    ChargerAddress  ChargerStatus   ChargerType     ChargerLat  ChargerLng  IsActive    PinType
0   39  Mod-3 Tip-2 22kW & Mod-1/2 3,7kW RFID   İSPARK Haldun Alagaş    İSPARK Haldun Alagaş    OFF     Mod-3 Tip-2 & Mod-1 Schuko  41.02620760142811   29.105417132377625  True    dev
1   48  GCS11623BNA1WN  Brisa Akademi   Brisa Akademi   OFF     Mod-3 Tip-2     40.75996813647878   29.98842716217041   True    dev
2   53  2 x Mod-3 Tip-2 3,7kW   KKB     KKB     OFF     Mod-3 Tip-2     40.99726137817314   29.099231958389282  True    dev
3   55  2 x Mod-3 Tip-2 22kW RFID   Ofishane    Ofishane    OFF     Mod-3 Tip-2     41.084529   28.979847000000063  True    dev
4   57  2 x Mod-3 Tip-2 22kW RFID   Lounge-2    Lounge-2    OFF     Mod-3 Tip-2     41.04003463723342   28.764374256134033  True    dev
...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...
111     6218    Mod-4 Tip-2 CCS 180(2x90)kW     TAMTEX TEKSTİL  TAMTEX TEKSTİL  OFF     Mod-4 Tip-2 CCS     41.209098   27.844295   True    dev
112     6219    Mod-4 Tip-2 CCS 120(2x60)kW     GERSAN ELEKTRİK ÇAYCUMA     GERSAN ELEKTRİK ÇAYCUMA     OFF     Mod-4 Tip-2 CCS     41.4073     32.127965   True    dev
113     6220    Mod-3 Tip-2 2x22kW  Safir Garage Otomotiv Turizm Tic. Ltd. Şti.     Safir Garage Otomotiv Turizm Tic. Ltd. Şti.     OFF     Mod-3 Tip-2     40.929214   29.308886   True    dev
114     6221    Mod-3 Tip-2 22kW    CİHAN ET KASAP BORNOVA  CİHAN ET KASAP BORNOVA  OFF     Mod-3 Tip-2     38.448616   27.208421   True    dev
115     6222    Mod-3 Tip-2 22kW    TUZ TERAPİ MERKEZİ-Tuzluca Kaymakamlığı     TUZ TERAPİ MERKEZİ-Tuzluca Kaymakamlığı     OFF     Mod-3 Tip-2     40.049999   43.66459    True    dev

116 rows × 10 columns
```

Comment: Thanks. How can i learn about these request methods and how can i find which parameter i have to use to get the data i desired from maps like you did? Because i want to do the same thing for the couple of other websites that have same kind of maps.

Comment: You're welcome @EfeDeğirmenci. You can see the network calls made by a web page by opening Dev Tools in browser -- under Network tab.